# Prove that we can't cover a 8x8 square with two 1x1 squares removed from two opposite corners with 1x2 rectangles

Tags: graph-theory

Imagine an 8x8 square. Remove two 1x1 squares from two opposite corners. So now you have a shape containing 62 squares. Call it S.

We want to cover S with 1x2 rectangles. Prove that we can't do this.

Note : This question could be related to Hall's theorem on matchings. But i don't know how to convert the question to a graph.

Comment: Parity. Colour squares alternately black and white like a chessboard. Dominos always cover one black and one white square.

Comment: @almagest would you please explain it more ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple example of the colouring technique. Colour the squares alternately like a chessboard. Then the two removed squares have the same colour, so we are left with an unequal number of black and white squares. But a domino always covers one black square and one white square, so we cannot completely cover the remaining squares with dominos.